# Why isn't the EU commission elected directly by EU citizens?

Tags: election, european-union

The EU commission consists of 28 members elected by the governments of the 28 EU states. This leads to people complaining that the EU is "[undemocratic](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jun/13/is-the-eu-undemocratic-referendum-reality-check)" since some of its major institutions are not under direct control of EU citizens.

What were the reasons which were stated during the EU founding for having the commissioners appointed by the member state governments and not elected by the EU citizens?

Comment: It's not a full answer, but it's probably worth noting that the percentages of the total population in  the largest and smallest states in the EU (16% in Germany versus 0.08% in Malta) are even more extreme than in the US (12% in California versus 0.18% in Wyoming). And that's while still including the UK.

Comment: "Couldn't the system work in the same way as the Senate does in the US?" Note that originally, US presidential elections were done in an indirect fashion (or were supposed to be, at least). The populations of individual states were intended to vote for people to cast their personal votes for president rather than the current methodologies. I'm not really sure of the politics behind why that evolved to the current system with essentially proxy voting, though.

Comment: Politics.SE is generally not a good place for idea brainstorming. If you are interested in opinions of other people for a political idea you have, you might rather bring this up on a more discussion-oriented website.

Comment: @Philipp I'm only asking about the historical reasons and the future perspectives

Comment: @JonathanReez I edited the question to ask specifically about historical reasons. A future perspective is hard to come by, because we can not tell the future.

Comment: Note that the European parliament was not elected directly by the citizens until 1979; one could argue that the EU was *not* created to be democratic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, the EU started small, as the European Coal and Steel Community, which already had a somewhat similar institutional structure, with a commission, a parliament, a council representing the member states and a court. The EEC and ultimately the EU grew out of this with an increasingly larger role and increasingly awkward compromises. From that perspective, I am not sure you should expect to find a point where an explicit decision was made to not elect EU commissioners directly, certainly not around the time it was founded. Maybe it was discussed when preparing the failed 2004 *Treaty establishing a Constitution for Europe*?

Beyond that, it's extremely difficult to imagine how such a system would look like or come about. In spite of all the changes like the direct election and increased role of the parliament or the election of the Commission's president by the parliament, the member states remain firmly in charge and direct election would fundamentally upset the balance of the EU institutions.

Finally, some member states have no tradition of electing anyone to public office, instead relying heavily on proportional voting on a list and coalition-building. That too could pose a serious challenge (think of a country like Belgium).

Comment: About the "no tradition of electing anyone to public office": The selection of the EU commission is how all offices are filled in The Netherlands. The Dutch don't even get to elect their mayor - they are selected by the nation-wide government.